# XSS Prevention, Tidy vs Purifier?

Tags: xss, ckeditor, tidy, htmlpurifier

Greetings,

I'm trying to prevent XSS and improper html from input fields using CKEditor (a javascript WYSIWYG editor).

How should I filter this data on the server side?  The two options I'm comparing are PHP Tidy and HTML Purifier.  I'm interested in speed, security, and valid nesting.

**Edit:**

According to HTML Purifier, Tidy does not prevent XSS.  So, let me specify that I would first pass the user input through

`strip_tags($input,'<img><a><li><ol><ul><b><br>');` before passing to Tidy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML Purifier restricts the input beyond what `strip_tags` can.  `strip_tags` would not strip JavaScript from the attributes of the tags you are allowing.  I definitely recommend using HTML Purifier.  HTML Purifier is not fast, but add/edit executions are usually less frequent than views so performance is less of an issue.

Comment: Also, HTML Purifier is a one-stop-shop, so you don't need to pass the code to Tidy afterward.

Comment: Just found this comparison, and it mentions `strip_tags` and Tidy. http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison